# Symfony2 include and access to the variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I dont have access to variables when try to include other file. 
I try to add with keyword in include but dont work, all time i get message:

> Variable "entity" does not exist in
>   ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post:last_post.html.twig at line 6

First i have indexAction() where i list all published blog post.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post')->getAllPublishedPosts();

    return $this->render('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'posts' => $posts
    ));
}
```

And have method where list only last posts

```
public function lastPostAction($count = 1)
{
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post')->getLastPosts($count);

    return $this->render('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post:last_post.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity
    ));
}
```

Problem is in this file in block sidebar. I try to include other file where i fetch only 1 last post.

```
{% extends 'ISLabBundlesBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {# Fetch all post#}
    {% if posts %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            <article class="blog">
                <div class="date"><time datetime="{{ post.created|date('c') }}">{{ post.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time></div>
                <header><h2> {{ post.title }} </h2></header>
                <p> {{ post.body }} </p>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {% include 'ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post:last_post.html.twig'%}
{% endblock %}
```

And here is file what i try to include:

```
<h2>Last Posts</h2>

<div class="blog">
    <ul>
        {% for item in entity %}
            <li><a href="">{{item.title}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

What i do wrong? And how to slove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass entity to your index template:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post')->getAllPublishedPosts();
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post')->getLastPosts(1);

    return $this->render('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'entity' => $entity,
    ));
}
```

It's also possible (and probably better) to do this with an embedded controller:

```
{% block sidebar %}
    {{ render(controller('ISLabBundlesBlogBundle:Post:lastPost', {
    'count': 1
})) }}
{% endblock %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html (search for Embedding Controllers)